# Zend auth inside doctrine2 entity repository

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

I am trying to create a method inside a doctrine 2 entity in zend framework. It is just to keep the code DRY. I want to retrieve the user object if they are logged in, and FALSE other wise:

```
 public function getCurrentUserId() {
        //returns false if not logged in, user object otherwise
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        $id = $auth->getidentity();
        $user = $this->_em->getRepository('Entities\User')
                ->findOneByid($id);
        if (is_null($user))
            return false;
        else
        return $user;
    }

}
```

This works fine within a controller action, but causes the following error here:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader::loadClass(): Failed opening required '/var/www/myswap/application/models/Repositories/Zend_Auth.php'
```

Why, and how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess and assume you're using namespaces since it looks like that.

On the line where you use `Zend_Auth`, prefix it with a \ - eg. `$auth = \Zend_Auth::getInstance();`

The reason for this is that namespaces in PHP are relative. Thus, if you try to use just `Zend_Auth` it assumes you want an object in the current namespace. By prefixing it with a \, you're telling it you want `Zend_Auth` from root.

I'd suggest familiarizing yourself with the [namespaces manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)